# Why isn't my UIAlertView getting dismissed on the screen before my view gets pushed on the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

Here is the code in order of calls. A `UIAlertView` is on the screen when this chunk of code gets called:

```
[upcAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];
```

The problem is the `UIAlertView` does NOT remove from the screen by the time `editController` appears. I need these things to happen because I have some loading going on in the `viewWillAppear` of the `editController` so I want to add a quick progress wheel (but I need the dialog gone). This code is called from the main thread.

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: What does startAnimatingProgress do?

Comment: Just puts up a progress wheel over an imageview on top of the view. Just a UI thing. If you comment that line out, the same problem occurs with the UIAlertView. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) documentation, more importantly the method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

When this method is called you could then push the viewcontroller, so that you know it is dismissed before pushing.

Like so:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I was using ActionSheet delegates, which caused the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your UIAlertView conform to the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) protocol?

You will need to updated your:

.h file

```
@interface YourClass : YourClassSuperClass <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

.m file

```
UIAlertView *alert = //alloc init
[alert setDelegate: self];
```

add this method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   switch (buttonIndex)

    case(0):
    {
      //Cancel button
    }
      break;

    case(..n):
    {
      //All other buttons
    }
      break;

    default:
    {
      //should never be thrown
    } 
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check uialerview delegate  UIAlertViewDelegate 
Sent to the delegate when the user clicks a button on an alert view.
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
}
//Sent to the delegate after an alert view is dismissed from the screen.
alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
{
}
```